# "ERROR: cannot verify www.youtube.com's certificate" with "wget 'http://www.youtube.com'"?

Tags: macos, ssl, terminal, openssl, wget

I seem to be having some kind of openssl/certificates issue I can't figure out. Using `wget 'http://www.youtube.com'` gives me the following certificates error (other sites like amazon and google work, though):

```
--2015-05-07 11:10:26--  http://www.youtube.com/
Resolving www.youtube.com... 74.125.239.102, 74.125.239.98, 74.125.239.101, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com|74.125.239.102|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.youtube.com/ [following]
--2015-05-07 11:10:26--  https://www.youtube.com/
Connecting to www.youtube.com|74.125.239.102|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.youtube.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.youtube.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.
```

First I tried reinstalling openssl with
`~ > brew uninstall openssl
~ > brew install openssl`
Nothing changed.

I tried `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect youtube.com:443 -CAfile /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` but this continues to give me a `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)` full output:

```
testenv3 > /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect youtube.com:443 -CAfile /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4500 bytes and written 474 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: BE12D954ABDF74775FCCDBD467C6494D2F5F93FC5C582F6086B42CB7F5A3C5CD
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 57AB75014EBE5C3CF5B617033D2EAFCA29780953F00FAE65C7BA9945202474717AA713F7E79B51C88007DE2A88559F62
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 6e 35 b6 f5 87 7f fc 8c-bd 57 35 a3 b9 89 15 4d   n5.......W5....M
    0010 - fe 9b d1 cf 05 7e b1 46-66 06 83 cd 83 ec ea f7   .....~.Ff.......
    0020 - 3f 2a a5 56 97 b3 76 c1-0d eb a4 d4 57 fd bb 23   ?*.V..v.....W..#
    0030 - a6 5a ea 63 17 cd 8d 47-f1 80 a5 d9 c8 74 d7 0f   .Z.c...G.....t..
    0040 - b2 f7 63 5a 9a fd 0f 2f-3d 95 96 07 54 89 51 cf   ..cZ.../=...T.Q.
    0050 - 7b d2 79 3f 9b ff 14 ed-af d8 cf dd 29 bd de 3d   {.y?........)..=
    0060 - 70 c1 ff 6b 5d d3 78 a7-62 f4 df 25 05 be 2c 94   p..k].x.b..%..,.
    0070 - 96 20 54 a2 70 8d 25 5c-75 93 ab f1 0b 1a 2a 29   . T.p.%\u.....*)
    0080 - 5b 1c 2c fb 64 80 73 84-c7 0a 27 f9 57 39 d0 81   [.,.d.s...'.W9..
    0090 - df dd 17 ff 3e 0a 37 5e-32 d3 8b 65 49 6f a4 e9   ....>.7^2..eIo..
    00a0 - cf 01 76 3b                                       ..v;

    Start Time: 1430847495
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

I also tried `echo | openssl s_client -connect youtube.com:443` and here is that output:

```
(testenv3)testenv3 > echo | openssl s_client -connect youtube.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3999 bytes and written 444 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 10775C02A73AB2D86F618C26491521BAC0EF8FAB670C7BEFC7F1FAA223064A57
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B7D9845159D987F16A7E1A847C049E1E2A703590C4846731ACCB12B34A5056900BAFEF75A461E999A786B258C12E87AC
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1430785075
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

I don't know what else to do from here and I have little to no understanding of openssl and certificates. What exactly do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Reinstalling `openssl` probably isn't helpful here. Have you tried reinstalling and upgrading `wget`? How does `curl` (which comes with the OS) behave? I'm not currently able to reproduce this problem with brew's wget.

Comment: @Rob Latest `libcurl` is build against `Security.framework` and uses native OS X certificates.

Comment: I know; that's why I want to test against it.

Comment: And check that `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` exists. It should have been created when you installed OpenSSL, and is built from the Mac's keychain. It's conceivable that this file was corrupted, and uninstalling openssl didn't remove it (and that it being there gets in the way of openssl recreating it when you reinstall). You can also pass that path to `wget` as the cert file to explicitly test against. That'll tell you if it's possibly a problem in the cert file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You may be affected by this bug: https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg38674.html

Comment: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem exists. I have tried deleting it and the whole contents of the folder while re-installing. It seems to affect anything using openssl, curl returns nothing for youtube.com, and youtube-dl also gives the same error, so it is not a wget issue. They all work for other domains like google, amazon, yahoo.com, etc.

Comment: Interesting baf, so I guess just keep waiting and updating openssl until this resolves?